# How to change default search engine in firefox running on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, search-engines

I did similar threads on this issue, I modified browser.search.defaultenginename and browser.search.defaulturl to Google, it still comes back with Yahoo. I am stuck, not sure how to change the defaults

Comment: the easiest way to see what's left is to search for the keyword "yahoo" itself in about:config and see what keys are still left with yahoo value

Comment: no there are 3 flags and they don't work

Comment: have you tried the keyword.url?

Comment: I did, didn't work (FF on Ubuntu)

Comment: is there any plugin of yahoo? have you tried reset firefox?

Comment: I did re-start Firefox and there are no Yahoo plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have a **Yahoo bar** installed in your browser, you should be able to change the search engine by simply selecting the name from the "Search" field (next to the address bar) without going into **about:config**. I think you have something from Yahoo that's putting it back, or your preferences are owned by some other user id for some reason. Try resetting the permissions on your ~/.mozilla directory like:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.mozilla; sudo chmod -R u+w ~/.mozilla
```

Comment: No its a multi-user Ubuntu system and I don't have an Yahoo toolbar. Even if I change it manually to Google, it comes back with Yahoo on re-start.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i'm using `ubuntu 12.04`

open Firefox in URL bar type `about:config` and press enter

in search bar type keyword.URL after locating double click on it and modify it's value to

> For Yahoo: http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=
>
> For Bing: http://www.bing.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=
>
> For Google: http://www.google.com/search?&q=

DONE.

Example

changing default search engine to yahoo

[image]